# A Combinatorial Question to Solve a System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have $N$ integer-valued variables $i_1$, $i_2$, $\cdot\cdot\cdot$, $i_N$, such that each variable can take integer values from 0 to $k$, and the sum of these $N$ variables is also equal to $k$. Formally, we want to solve the constrained linear equation:

\begin{cases}
i_1+i_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot + i_N = k \\
0 \leq i_j \leq k & \text{where $1\leq j \leq N$}
\end{cases}

Is there anyone know why **the number of solutions** is equal to $\binom{k+N-1}{N-1}$?

Thanks in advance very much.

Comment: There's a common explanation that often goes by the catch phrase "stars and bars" illustration.

Comment: Yes, it's the number of solutions. How can we get this number?

Comment: The question has been asked and answered many times on this site. If you do a search for "stars and bars" site:math.stackexchange.com you'll probably find several of them.

Comment: Note that if the sum is $k$, limiting each $i_r \le k$ really doesn't limit anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Assume you align $k$ red balls on the floor.

Now take $N-1$ blue balls and place them in between the red balls.

This separates the red balls into $N$ sets of cardinality $i_j$, and of course the sum of the $i_j$'s is $k$.

Now how many ways do you have do that?

As many as the number of ways of picking $N-1$ balls among $k+N-1$.